# Is it necessary to include の in the following?

Tags: translation, particle-の

English: I'm an American who was born in South America.

Google Translate: 私は南アメリカで生まれたアメリカ人です。

My translation: 私は南アメリカで生まれたのアメリカ人です。

Should there be a の there? Why or why not?

Comment: BTW 南米 would be more common. 南アメリカ looks like south US (アメリカ南部).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There **must not** be の. In general, の is a **noun**-linking particle, and there must never be の between a relative clause (verb) and a modified noun. I don't speak Chinese, but I know this is a very common mistake Chinese speakers make.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I was the one who thought there should be a の. I'm not sure why.

Comment: You're right. Another mistake. I changed it to 私. Thanks for pointing that out.